# card view arrangement inside layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to create a layout that looks like this

[image]

and if the gadget that will view it is larger like tablet it will look like this

[image]

how can I achieve that?

here is my layout but its wrong

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/header"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginRight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:fontFamily="@font/tahoma"
                android:text="HOME"
                android:textColor="@color/dark_gray"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <!-- Real content goes here -->
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ScrollView
                android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />


            <ScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                android:paddingRight="20dp"
                android:paddingTop="16dp"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView

                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="180dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

                            <ImageView

                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                                android:src="@drawable/coverage_plan" />

                        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="20sp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

                        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView

                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="180dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

                            <ImageView

                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                                android:src="@drawable/visit_man" />

                        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                    </LinearLayout>


                </LinearLayout>
            </ScrollView>

            />
        </FrameLayout>

        <!-- The navigation drawer -->
        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/navigation"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_header"
            app:itemIconTint="@color/darker_gray"
            app:itemTextColor="@color/black"
            app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</LinearLayout
```

I hope someone helps me with my issue that the only i need make still same size regardless of witdth. my sample displayed it well but it stretches when using tablets

Comment: Use ConstraintLayout

Comment: how can i make it?

Comment: Please have e look at this https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/
Replace your linearlayout inside scrollview by ConstraintLayout

Comment: still the same even though i make some changes on match parents

Comment: You should use the chain functions. More info: look under the chain section in https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/